# It is possible to parse text from html editor not using v-html in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

My project has admin panel and main page. On admin panel I can create posts using HTML editor (VueEditor in this example) post that in data base looks like this:

`<p>Here is some test text from VueEditor</p>`

Then, I want to parse it one the main page, but, of course, without `<p>` tag, so I use this:

`<p v-html='item.plot'></p>`

And here is a problem, IDE tells:

`ESLint: 'v-html' directive can lead to XSS attack.(vue/no-v-html)`

Is this really that dangerous? Should I parse it some other way?

Comment: `v-html` should not be used to display user generated content, otherwise a malicious user could create a post containing arbitrary JavaScript that will be executed on the page to steal the session cookie, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is really that dangerous.

Consider what happens when I create the post.

```html
Hi I'm Dave this is my <script>alert('pwned,' + document.cookie)</script> post!
```

I can now run arbitrary JS code on your website and steal login info for every user you serve this code too.

I'm not super familiar with vue in particular but most frameworks have an easy way to output sanitized html. I think this is `{{ itme.plot }}`  in vue. This will not render an actual  (or any other tag) but an escaped version `&lt;script&gt;` which the browser will not interpret as actual code.

There are a million other way to do XSS if you let me inject my own HTML in your website.

Comment: But what if only I have access to admin panel? I mean, is it dangerous from main page, not admin panel, because no one has access to it, only me.

Comment: @dokichan Is doing it the right way any harder? Best to practice doing things the safe way so you don't do it the wrong way when it does matter. All it takes is letting on XSS though to be pwned. You are right that if only you see this page it's fine but what if one day you decide to allow users to make posts and you reuse this? Will you remember what you need to fix?